# Trouble installing phonegap plugin push with Ionic 2

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

I'm currently trying to develop an application with some plugins, here is the list :

```
com.googlemaps.ios 2.5.0 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crop 0.3.1 "CropPlugin"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.9.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.1.1 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.15 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 2.0.1 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.4-dev "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.2.1 "SocialSharing"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
info.protonet.imageresizer 0.1.1 "Image Resizer"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.1.0 "PushPlugin"
```

Since I installed the PushPlugin, I have no more possibility to build the app, I have the following error :

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
   > For input string: "+"
```

I tried to edit project.properties, build.gradle.. From what i read on internet, this is a conflict version between different google based plugins. I can't figure out how to make these plugins work together.. Thank you in advance for help !

Comment: Since you are using ionic 2, why don't use the ionic plugins available for you?

Comment: Ionic native plugins are based on phonegap/cordova plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solve it as follows:

Go to platform-> android -> project.properties and assign a version number for `com.google.android.gms:play-services-{}:11.0.1` ( Match all play service dependency version )

If you recompile now, it will complain about `google-services.json` file. You can create and download it from here. Save that file in the root folder of your ionic project.

It should recompile now without errors. You read through this [git](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1718) thread.

Comment: Is t hat google json file just a blank file or what? I am stuck at that part